# Get part of file name and assign it to variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a file name like this "C:\data\dbversion_1.0.2099.24765.txt". This filename varies throughout the day.

I want to get only last part of this file name "1.0.2099.24765" and assigne this value to any variable. (in general it should be data between "dbversion_" and ".txt")

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `dir` command to get the actual file name, parse its output by a `for /F` loop to get the pure file name with the extension split off, then use substring replacement to get everything after the (first) underscore `_`:

```
rem Let `dir` get the actual file name, parse its output by `for /F`:
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "C:\data\dbversion_*.txt"
') do (
    set "NAME=%%~nF"
)
rem Do substring replacement:
set "NAME=%NAME:*_=%"
rem Use variable `%NAME%` here:
echo "%NAME%"
```

---

A simple standard `for` loop achieves the same result either:

```
rem Let `for` get the actual file name:
for %%F in ("C:\data\dbversion_*.txt") do (
    set "NAME=%%~nF"
)
rem Do substring replacement:
set "NAME=%NAME:*_=%"
rem Use variable `%NAME%` here:
echo "%NAME%"
```